# Rails 7 deploy puma error - rbenv: no such command `default'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Tengo ese problema. Ya capistrano hace el error, pero cuando entro a mi sitio me sale **We're sorry, but something went wrong.**

Cuando veo mi puma.error.log sale

```
rbenv: no such command `default'
rbenv: no such command `default'
rbenv: no such command `default'
rbenv: no such command `default'
rbenv: no such command `default'
rbenv: no such command `default'
rbenv: no such command `default'
rbenv: no such command `default'
rbenv: no such command `default'
rbenv: no such command `default'
```

Ngix.error.log

```
2022/03/11 22:24:52 [crit] 89082#89082: *37 connect() to unix:///home/user/apps/mysite/shared/tmp/sockets/mysite-puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 190.120.254.15, server: app.mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/myuser/apps/mysite/shared/tmp/sockets/mysite-puma.sock:/", host: "app.mysite.com"
2022/03/11 22:25:51 [info] 89082#89082: *38 client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while waiting for request, client: 190.120.254.15, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

(claro, mysite es mi sitio y user es mi usuario)

y deploy.rb

```
lock "~> 3.16.0"

# replace obvious parts
set :application, "myapp"
set :repo_url, "my_repo"

set :user, 'myuser'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '3.1.0'

set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

append :linked_files, "config/master.key"
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "public/uploads"
```

Comment: Obviamente estoy remplazando myapp, mysite otros datos por datos de mi servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace años que no uso capistrano, pero claramente por el `rbenv: no such command 'default'` estás llamando en alguna parte `rbenv default`, lo cual no es parte [de los comandos permitidos](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#command-reference) por `rbenv`.
Si no has sido tu, quizás pueda deberse a la versión de [capistrano-rbenv](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv) que estás usando, quizás tiene algún tipo de conflicto con tu versión de `capistrano`?

Comment: Borré todo, lo rehice de nuevo y usé passenger. Con eso bastó :) gracias